# What is your experience with Adempiere CRM for customization and development?

Tags: customization, crm, platform, erp, adempiere

What is your experience with [ADempiere CRM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adempiere/)? The demos and docs are good; what are you experiences in developing and customizing with it?

Is there a reason to go with [Compiere CRM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compiere/) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADempiere is feature rich Open Source ERP application.
It has more functionality compared to Compiere or OpenBravo and is easier to customise and develop with.

For example, we maintain ADempiere sources always to be compilable. Something which is hard to say for Compiere sources, which require at least 30 minutes to get them compiling in Eclipse.

Many different developers have contributed extension modules which are freely available from ADempiere SVN Server.

ADempiere has big wiki with documentation and customisation examples.

ADempiere IRC channel is quite active and friendly.

Comment: So you are saying that in all ramifications, Adempiere is better than Compiere.

Comment: Please I need sample db file that I could use for my compiere installation. I am having problems with creating and dropping a db when using the wizard that came with my compiere installation. So I want something like a .dmp, .sql that I can simply use to restore in postgress